# Neo4j How do you keep property but group sender nodes in email data?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am working with email data in neo4j.  I have the same `sender` for all 5 emails and 5 different `recipients`.  The sender has a property `the link` in the email that was sent.  In most databases I can do a `groupby` to have one node the `name` 'tv.test.com', to many recipients "One-to-many"

```
//CREATE SAMPLE NODES
CREATE (sender1:Sender{name:'tv.test.com', url:'https://www.tv.test.com/5219922-h1=Ez1bLCN'})
CREATE (sender2:Sender{name:'tv.test.com', url:'https://www.tv.test.com/5218922-h1=Ez1bLCN'})
CREATE (sender3:Sender{name:'tv.test.com', url:'https://www.tv.test.com/5259922-h1=Ez1bLCN'})
CREATE (sender4:Sender{name:'tv.test.com', url:'https://www.tv.test.com/5213822-h1=Ez1bLCN'})
CREATE (sender5:Sender{name:'tv.test.com', url:'https://www.tv.test.com/5215922-h1=Ez1bLCN'})
CREATE (recipient1:Recipient{name:'rob@test.com'})
CREATE (recipient2:Recipient{name:'willy@test.com'})
CREATE (recipient3:Recipient{name:'milo@test.com'})
CREATE (recipient4:Recipient{name:'gonzo@test.com'})
CREATE (recipient5:Recipient{name:'leroy@test.com'})
CREATE (sender1)-[:TO]->(recipient1)
CREATE (sender2)-[:TO]->(recipient2)
CREATE (sender3)-[:TO]->(recipient3)
CREATE (sender4)-[:TO]->(recipient4)
CREATE (sender5)-[:TO]->(recipient5)
```

What it currently looks like:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like where I can keep the property and group by name:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these one-to-many or many-to-many relationships?  If yes then you can move the URL from sender to the recipient node, that would solve your problem.
If not then you can move the URL to relationship property.

The recommended way is to create a new type of node `Email` and connect the `Sender` and the `Recipient` to it.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Didn't notice that

Comment: You may need to modify your data model if you wan only one node for each sender name

Comment: Are these one-to-many or many-to-many relationships? If one-to-many then you can move the URL from sender to the recipient node, that would solve your problem

Comment: If there is no other way I am going to have to do that. Thank you @Raj

Comment: You can also move the URL to relationship property